# Crear una tabla con medidas DAX - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

La tabla que cree con medidas DAX, quiero conectarlo al modelo de datos, es decir, crear una tabla nueva y que esta tabla nueva se conecte al modelo de datos. 
Como lo harían?

Gracias!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

no creo que sea posible tener tanto suma como porcentaje de una misma columna juntos. Lo que puedes hacer este tener dos columnas, una con la suma y otra con el porcentaje.

La forma más sencilla de realizar este pedido es como indica la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes agregar dos veces la columna a verificar e ir a la flechita hacia abajo que contiene dentro de valores de la visualización para expandir el menú que muestra la imagen y seleccionar Porcentaje del total general.

Espero que te sirva